# A Perfect Polish

Tags: riddle, word, wordplay, rhyme, poetry

> *I slide with a rustle 
>  Of needles that hang, 
>  To glide in the tunnel 
>  And scrape every fang. 
>  
>  I spread with a slither 
>  Of slime and a slew, 
>  To shred and to wither 
>  The gold from the chew.*

***What could I be?***

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you are a

> Toothbrush

I slide with a rustle

> Noise of a toothbrush is a rustle

Of needles that hang,

> Bristles

To glide in the tunnel

> The mouth.

And scrape every fang.

> The teeth

I spread with a slither 
Of slime and a slew,

> When coated in toothpaste and foam.

To shred and to wither 
The gold from the chew.

> Gold here could be figurative or may refer to gold fillings. The process is separation of food from the teeth.

Comment: $(+1)$: You did it again! Good job! I tried to be metaphorical to try and make the clues a little more concealed... but of course that didn't work for you! I will give you a tick in $24$ hours from now. Well done! :D **Edit:** (ROT13) V abgvprq gung gur nafjre pbhyq nyfb or gbbgucnfgr. Vs lbh'er ernqvat guvf, jung nafjre qb lbh guvax fhvgf orfg?

Comment: Anyway, congratulations yet again! $\color{green}{\checkmark}$